# Why typing None in interactive Python prints nothing?

Tags: python, interactive, repr

When`python` is started interactively  it will evaluate expressions like `[]` and print the result converted to string or execute statements like `i = 1`. Since statements do not have a value, if they do not write anything to the terminal, nothing will be printed. However, when I typed `None` as an expression, Python prints nothing, not even `'None'`. At the first glance I thought `repr(None)` will return an empty string but I was wrong. So why Python makes a special case with `None` by printing nothing at all?

```
>>> None
>>>
>>> repr(None)
'None'
>>> str(None)
'None'
```

Answer (score 2):

In interactive mode, the result of any expression-statement is printed *only* if it is not `None`. This behaviour is described in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements).

> Expression statements are used (mostly interactively) to compute and write a value [...]
>
> In interactive mode, if the value is not `None`, it is converted to a
>   string using the built-in `repr()` function and the resulting string is
>   written to standard output

The reason for that is that most functions that have side-effects return `None`. It would be annoying to have `None` spammed in the console.

```
>>> lst.append(1)
None
>>> lst.append(2)
None
>>> lst.append(3)
None
>>> print('Please stop...')
Please stop...
None
```

Comment: Joyful example.

Comment: Nice shot for bring me the doc that I missed.

Comment: @cgsdfc Yes, the doc about that is actually hidden in the grammar specification of Python, it can be hard to find the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Because otherwise all function calls that didn't return anything would print `None`.

Comment: Good reason. Can I say if python finds out the result to print is `None`, it simply skips to print a prompt?